# Condition for borderless manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Suppose we are given a manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is borderless (i.e. $\partial M = \emptyset$). I am looking for a condition that only border less manifolds satisfy. I exptect something that is similar to the definition of an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align}
\forall x \in U: \exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t. if } d(x,y) < \epsilon \text{ then } y \in M.
\end{align}
However, in the case of the manifold that $y$ may not be an arbitrary element from $\mathbb{R}^n$, no it has to satisfy $y \in M$, as well.

This is where I am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.s.: could it also be related to open covers ?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a manifold already enforces this condition! You have to extend this definition (by allowing charts with domain $\mathbb R^{n-1}\times [0,\infty)$) in order to define manifolds with boundary.

You could say that the condition for a *manifold with boundary* to have $\partial M = \emptyset$ is that it has no boundary charts; i.e. all of its charts have domains that are open sets in $\mathbb R^n$. (Whatever your particular definition of manifold-with-boundary, it should have a special case near the boundary - so by stipulating that the special case doesn't occur, we can enforce zero boundary.)

Comment: Can you come up with a condition when $M$ is a Riemannian manifold ?

Comment: @Yamamoto: if it's Cauchy-complete then having zero border is equivalent to being geodesically complete.

Comment: I'll try to figure out what that means. Thanks !